# Expand div in a grid thumbnail with jquery

Tags: jquery

how to make the ul li grid expanded like this picture below >

[image]

i mean, when i click each of the thumbnail, the bigger box will expanded below them ( each thumbnail that clicked ), if possible like toggle or slide up / down effect

it's more like google image function, but i just need the proper way to expand a box in grid, without plugins

Thanks

Comment: write your own then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
$("#items li").click(function(){
  
  $("#items li.big-cloned").remove();
  var li=$(this);
  var cloned=li.clone().addClass('big-cloned');
  li.after(cloned);
  
  
});
```

```css
ul li{

  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
  margin:10px;
  text-align:center;
}

li.big-cloned{
   display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 89%;
  margin: 0 9%;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="items">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
  <li>Ten</li>
  </ul>
```